# Python - How to get a column 'duration' with start and end time column in csv?

Tags: python, csv, duration

I have a problem in manipulating csv file.
In my csv file, there is a column 'Start Time' and 'Complete Time' and I want to get a column 'Duration' using it.
When I tried `duration = row[2] - row[1]`, it showed me an error message

`'unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`.

Comment: You would do well to post some code here, it makes it a lot easier to help you. Also, you can't calculate differences of strings, you need to convert them to dates first. Check out [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) for that.

Comment: 1) Check out how to import a CSV to pandas dataframe - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html.  
2) Read here how to work with time and dates in pandas - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html
3) See here how to export a pandas dataframe back to csv: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: Please post the code you have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data you obtained from csv file is of str type, you can not do the operation:

```
duration = row[2] - row[1]
```

I would advice you to first convert row[2] and row[1] content, and then do the operation.

```
import time
complete_time = time.strptime(row[2])
start_time = time.strptime(row[1])
duration = complete_time - start_time
```